# How do deal with maven lifecycle when ordering does not match needs

Tags: maven

I have a maven project that, as parts of build, does two things:

- Generates an sqlite database by running an SQL script. It seems to me that database is a resource, so the logical phase to do this would be `generate-resources`,
- Generates source code, which obviously should be done under `generate-sources` phase.

But, I cannot do it like this, as the source code is generated based on that database, and the lifecycle runs `generate-sources` before `generate-resources`. I can obviously run both goals during the same phase, but this seems dirty for me. Note however that the sqlite database is only used to generate sources, not for anything else, especially it does not get packed into final artifacts.

What can I do to have the project working and looking correct?

To better explain what I'm trying to achieve: I'm generating sources via [JOOQ](https://www.jooq.org/), and it needs an existing database to generate. However I don't feel like having a binary blob in my SCM, so I'd like to generate that database on the fly.

Comment: What about using another phase like `process-resources`? https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference

Comment: Running both creating DB and generating code in `process-resources`? Would technically work, though IMHO looks even more dirty than sticking to `generate-sources` or `generate-resources`, as neither of those operations fits `process-resources`.

Comment: Yes I see but you need to be sure to use two different life cycle phases to get reliable results.